# Consulting a shared prolog file

Tags: java, command-line, network-programming, prolog

I am trying to consult a Prolog file on my Ubuntu PC which is shared on LAN by remote Ubuntu PC. I want to do this using java code. So i tried the following java code

```
Runtime.getRunTime().exec("gnome-terminal -x swipl -s smb://remotePcI/sharedFolder/sharedFile.pl")
```

This gives the error **'Prolog initialisation failed.Script file does'nt exist'**.

Could someone pls help ?

Comment: Let's separate the problem from the fact that you're using Java. What happens if, on your Ubuntu client PC, you run `swipl -s smb://remotePcI/sharedFolder/sharedFile.pl`, does it access the file properly? If not, if you do `cat smb://remotePcI/sharedFolder/sharedFile.pl` do you see the contents of the file? If not, then you have an incorrect Samba reference to the shared file.

Comment: @lurker i just did a little experiment. I was able to open to the file using `gedit` but not by using `cat`. I also came to know that `gedit` mounts the shared folder and then opens the file using `cat`. So I think i would have to mount the folder before accessing it in client PC. Thanks to you for telling me to open file using `cat`.